# Creating Excel Macro

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a macro that basically does:

If cell A contains exact date from cell C, then ask "if you want to transfer data from cell C to A"

Not sure how complicated creating such macro. I'm new to Excel and macros.

Any help?

Comment: What do you have so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively what you're looking for

```
Sub Example()
    Dim msg as String
    If InStr(CellA, CellC) Then
        msg = MsgBox("Do you want to transfer data from cell C to cell A?", vbYesNo)
        If msg = vbYes Then
            CellA = CellC
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll have to update it with your references

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: If it solves your issue don't forget to mark it as solved (click the little tick to the left of the answer)

Comment: Will do, and yes it worked! Thank you!